# php: Anonymous function and arguments

Tags: php, function

I have an array of objects (from DB) and need to foreach this one before send to the viewer:

```
$data['contracts'] = array();

foreach ($contracts as $c) {
    $data['contracts'][] = array(
         'id' => $c->id,
         'num' => $c->num,
         'delay' => function ($c->date_added) {
              ... blablabla ... 
         },
    );
}
```

This examples returns an error because `$c->date_added` is uses, as workaround I must define additional variable before foreach loop:

```
$date_added = $c->date_added;
```

How can I use properties in anonymous functions without additional variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be easier:

```
// more stuff
'delay' => function ($c) { 
    $dateAdded = $c->date_added;
    // rest of bla bla bla...
},
// more stuff
```

Comment: I bet you mistyped here`->->` ;)